# SSRS Visibility expression based on parameter is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my SSRS Report, I have a parameter that takes multiple values, which are the following: all, top3, amazon, none

Then I have an expression where parts of my report should hide or be visible based on that parameter.

Here is my expression:

```
=iif(join(Parameters!Cities.Value, ",").Contains("all"), FALSE, TRUE)
```

So for every checkbox that is checked, I want it to be displayed. So it could just be all, or all and Amazon which should show both.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried `=iif(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Cities.Value, "all") > -1, FALSE, True)`
 and it didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Your parameter's not `All`?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm pretty sure my parameter is correct. So when "all" is not checked, I do not want that piece to be visible.

Comment: I figured it out, it is because I have to use "Hidden" and "Visible" for a map, not true and false.

Comment: I thought it might be due to Case Sensitivity - both .net functions are case sensitive and would not have matched if your parameter was `All`.